# Jquery error, Image upload does work

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, amazon-s3

Weird error, I use blueimp jquery file upload, to upload files from client-side to Node.js then Amazon S3 storage.

the code works perfect, the files does get to Amazon s3, but on client-side on the plugin I get this error: `Error SyntaxError: Unexpected token S`.

The Node.js code I'm using is the following:

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile(req.files.files[0].path, function (err, data) {
        var imageName = req.files.files[0].name
        /// If there's an error
        if(!imageName){
            console.log("There was an error")
            res.redirect("/");
            res.end();
        } else {
            var img_path = req.files.files[0].path;
           var file_read  = fs.readFile(img_path, function(err, data){
               var BucketName = 'webwedding/'+SSName;
               s3.createBucket({Bucket: BucketName}, function() {
                   var params = {Bucket: BucketName,ACL: "public-read" , Key: imageName, Body: data};
                   s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
                       res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
                       if (err) {
                           console.log(err)
                           res.end(err);
                       }
                       else      {
                           console.log('Uploaded ' + imageName +' To '+SSName);
                           res.end('Successfully uploaded data to webwedding\n');
                       }
                   });
               });
           });
        }
    });
});
```

I now came to understand that I need to JSON.stringly the result, but only cant manage to create the correct res.end result! trying to follow [Blueimp support](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/node/server.js#L67).

**Edit:**trying to add template to check results:

```
                   var files = [
                       {
                           "name": "picture1.jpg",
                           "size": 902604,
                           "url": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture1.jpg",
                           "thumbnailUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/thumbnail\/picture1.jpg",
                           "deleteUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture1.jpg",
                           "deleteType": "DELETE"
                       }]
                   res.end(JSON.stringify(files));
```

gives me that error on client side:

```
Error Empty file upload result
```

The error comes from fileupload.ui code, hope it's not too long, but I think I must show it so maybe someone can figure it out:

```
if (data.context) {
                    data.context.each(function (index) {
                        var file = files[index] ||
                                {error: 'Empty file upload result'};
                        deferred = that._addFinishedDeferreds();
                        that._transition($(this)).done(
                            function () {
                                var node = $(this);
                                template = that._renderDownload([file])
                                    .replaceAll(node);
                                that._forceReflow(template);
                                that._transition(template).done(
                                    function () {
                                        data.context = $(this);
                                        that._trigger('completed', e, data);
                                        that._trigger('finished', e, data);
                                        deferred.resolve();
                                    }
                                );
                            }
                        );
                    });
```

Comment: Remove `dataType : 'json'` from the ajax call you're using on the clientside, as you're just returning plain text, which is fine.

Comment: "Error Empty file upload result" still expacting something else

Comment: Do you get that error on the clientside ?

Comment: Yes adeneo, also edit the question, so more details, maybe helpful for solving issue